# Doubt about when complementary slackness theorem is useful

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

[source](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emlavrov/docs/482-spring-2020/lecture13.pdf):

> We can use complementary slackness to do two things:
>
> 1. Go from the optimal primal solution to the optimal dual solution, and vice versa.
> 2. Verify that a solution is optimal, by checking if there's a dual solution that goes with it.

In regard to (1.), I know that you can always retrieve the dual by taking the negative transpose. So I don't see why I would ever use (1.), when I could just take the negative transpose to retrieve the dual ... and by the Strong Duality Theorem, I know that if the objective values of the primal and dual are equals, then they are both optimal.

Am I correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I couldn't find Our what the key point of your question  Btw, you haven't mentioned 2. In your question.

Comment: basically, why is complementary slackness theorem useful when you can just take the negative transpose of the primal and check that the objective values of the primal and dual matches in order to determine whether they are both optimal. That's easier than what the complementary slackness theorem tells you to do. 

I hope that makes sense.